# Parsing datetime from String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string with

```
String a= "04/23/2014 12:00 AM"
DateTime.ParseExact(a, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This Shows an error

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact

Comment: Can I ask why you used 24 hour clock `HH` with an AM/PM designator `tt`? See [Custom Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @mason I guess OP is not aware of that `HH` means 24 hrs format

Comment: I don't understand why these questions/answers are so heavily upvoted despite the same question (with slight variations) being asked pretty much every hour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your format is specifying time in 24 hours format, but your string has time in 12 hour format. For parsing time your format should be `"hh:mm tt"`

```
String a = "04/23/2014 12:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> HH --- The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23. More
>   information: [The "HH" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier).
>
> hh --- The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12. More
>   information: [The "hh" Custom Format Specifier.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier)